# Do I condition a constant while computing the conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have this event $A$ and I know $P(A)$.

I also have a r.v. $T$, which is exponential with a given $\lambda$.

I want to compute ${\bf E}[T+5|A]$.

I remember that unconditionally, ${\bf E}[T+b]={\bf E}[T]+b$. But does it mean that ${\bf E}[T+b|A]={\bf E}[T|A]+b$ or do I have somehow to condition the constant $b$ as well?

Conditioning a constant seems weird to me, but on the other hand I have a hunch I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the distribution of $A$? Is that given?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[b\mid A]=b$, so...

Comment: @PIE Yes, but does it matter here? It's an even that another exponential random variable will be less or equal to 5.

Comment: @ClementC.  So, $[b|A]=b$, now I see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Linearity of Expectation holds for a conditional expectation too.

When $T$ is a random variable, $A$ is an event, and $b$ a constant, then:

$$\mathsf E(T+b\mid A) ~=~ \mathsf E(T\mid A)+b$$